# Xamarin forms Android class Library collection is read only vs 2017 15.6.4

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I need to create an Android class library and add Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.forms.Maps

So I created an empty project I get

> Nuget Xamarin forms  gives "this collection is read only" output
>
> Added package 'Xamarin.Forms.2.5.1.444934' to folder
>   'C:\MyTemp\TestApp\packages'
>
> Install failed. Rolling back...

So

I have cleared the nugetcache but nothing.

This is driving me mad and looked at bugzilla and it seems to be an issue but all the workaround do not fix it.

Can you create an android class library and add xamarin.forms and maps to it?

thanks

Comment: I believe this bug fixed in latest version, try to update VS to latest version (15.6.6) and try again.

Comment: Downloaded 15.6.6 still same problem

Comment: One thing I have noticed it works if you create an android blank app and not a classlibrary. what is the difference apart from the manifest ? can you convert it to a classlibrary?

Comment: Why you need ClassLibrary? Why didn't use Xamarin.Form project template in the first place?

Comment: Hi the reason I used an android class library is because I put all the code that is shared with  other application CustomRenderers,utils etc.. Should I have used something else ? this class library is used by 3-4  app. What would you have used?thanks

Comment: Hey, are you familiar with Xamarin.Form project template? it will create all projects for you (Shared, Android, iOS, Windows and of course you can ignore one or more of them)

Comment: the way i do it is this. 1) I create an app using prism template ,this create 4 projects app-Ios-and android template. then I have a set of core/framework class library that are shared among all the other xamarin applications. I might be missing the obvious but i will have a look now

Comment: It looks similar to default Xamarin.Form template, but I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with third party templates, using default Xamarin.Forms template works for me.

Comment: its the same ,after creating a Mobile app(xamarin Forms) template. I still need a project to put all the core stuff shared by all the apps. WHat project do you use for that .

Comment: No bro, the first app (not platform specific projects) is for your share codes. (_like UI and ..._). you don't need to add another project for that.

Comment: we have 10 mobile applications and we cannot replicate code,a bit like plugins ,we cannot copy and paste the same custom renderer into 10 project and we do not like to create links in tfs ,so we create a set of core projects that are shared among all the apps.A framework if you like.The only problem I have its that xamarin.forms.maps its playing up with nuget and they keep blaming each other. and I need  a solution for the interim process. THanks for your help and time

Comment: So create custom component for your need and then add that component (like other components/nugets) to your app(s). I mean you need your component not share project

Comment: we have a mixture components(like nuget) Helpers,utilities,customerrenders etc... ,I think we are going offtrack the problem remains using the latest xamarinforms-xamarinforms.maps nuget is not happy and I need a workaround soon.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have cleared the nuget cache and suppress the folder Cache at C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Xamarin.Android for resolve this problem